# Tokio mpsc closes channel when sender assigned to static

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am struggling to understand the behaviour of the following snippet:

```rust
use tokio::sync::mpsc::{error::SendError, unbounded_channel, UnboundedSender};
use std::sync::OnceLock;

static GSENDER: OnceLock<UnboundedSender<&'static str>> = OnceLock::new();

fn main() {
    let (sender, mut channel) = unbounded_channel();
    
    GSENDER.set(sender).unwrap();

    tokio::runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread()
        .worker_threads(1) // on a new thread
        .enable_all()
        .build()
        .unwrap()
        .spawn(async move {
            println!("[{:?}] Starting channel", chrono::Utc::now());

            while let Some(msg) = channel.recv().await {
                println!("[{:?}] Recvd: {msg}", chrono::Utc::now());
            }
            
            println!("[{:?}] Closing channel", chrono::Utc::now());
        });
       
    // Does not help, as it shouldn't anyway
    // std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
        
    if let Some(channel_in) = GSENDER.get() {
        if let Err(SendError(_)) = channel_in.send("test") {
            println!("[{:?}] Channel down", chrono::Utc::now());
        }
    } else {
        unreachable!()
    }
}
```

[Link to playground to reproduce](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e162a8adbeb59c9223e1e9ac90724f63)

New runtime is created, a future is spawned.
Then, `recv` is being polled.
Meanwhile, I get ahold of the sender half and attempt to send a message.
At this point, the reciever is either moved to the future, or (with the added sleep) it even is polling `recv`.

Why is the sender reporting that the channel is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All tasks spawned within a tokio runtime shut down (at the next `.await` point) when the runtime is dropped. The runtime here is a temporary, so it is dropped at the end of the statement. The task will only run until the first `.await` point.

Make the runtime a living variable and it'll work:

```rust
use std::sync::OnceLock;
use tokio::sync::mpsc::{error::SendError, unbounded_channel, UnboundedSender};

static GSENDER: OnceLock<UnboundedSender<&'static str>> = OnceLock::new();

fn main() {
    let (sender, mut channel) = unbounded_channel();

    GSENDER.set(sender).unwrap();

    let runtime = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread()
        .worker_threads(1) // on a new thread
        .enable_all()
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    runtime.spawn(async move {
        println!("[{:?}] Starting channel", chrono::Utc::now());

        while let Some(msg) = channel.recv().await {
            println!("[{:?}] Recvd: {msg}", chrono::Utc::now());
        }

        println!("[{:?}] Closing channel", chrono::Utc::now());
    });

    if let Some(channel_in) = GSENDER.get() {
        if let Err(SendError(_)) = channel_in.send("test") {
            println!("[{:?}] Channel down", chrono::Utc::now());
        }
    } else {
        unreachable!()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ccc1fc3286b3543e56dc3c03d6d7593e).

Comment: Thanks, I misread the documentation


> The provided future will start running in the background immediately when spawn is called, even if you don't await the returned JoinHandle.

Comment: Also note that there isn't a guarantee the "Recvd" message will be printed with this code, because after `channel_in.send()` the runtime could be dropped (when `main()` returns) before the task gets woken up.